# Нужно ли обособлять этот оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

Обязательно ли здесь обособление или оно, по современным правилам, вообще не нужно?

Европейский рынок(,) с участием фирм ФРГ, Великобритании, Франции, Италии, Швеции(,) в годовом объеме производства различных видов арматуры (клапаны, задвижки, краны, затворы) составляет 4,8 млрд евро.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Европейский рынок, с участием фирм ФРГ, Великобритании, Франции, Италии, Швеции, в годовом объеме производства различных видов арматуры (клапаны, задвижки, краны, затворы) составляет 4,8 млрд евро.

Думаю,что обособление делается в обязательном порядке. Обособленный оборот является несогласованным определением, причем он уточняет значение согласованного определения, стоящего перед существительным, раскрывает его содержание.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Vera, а что в Вашем понимании здесь согласованное определение и что - несогласованное? Неужели согласованное - "европейский"?

Comment: А что, не похоже? Согласование в роде, числе и падеже.

Comment: А если сказать так: европейский рынок, с его стремлением к укрупнению и глобализации, представляет собой... Ну или что-нибудь в этом роде... Тогда уж точно будет обособленное несогласованное определение после стоящего перед существительным согласованного...

Comment: "Обычный детерминизм с его стремлением к «естественным» объяснениям не хочет этого замечать". Здесь нет обособления. Вообще говоря, на обособление несогласованных определений влияют различные факторы, в том числе распространенность. определения, дополнительное обстоятельственное значение и др.

Comment: В первом примере  решающим фактором для обособления было пояснительное значение определения, во втором - добавочное значение причины.

Comment: Что такое европейский рынок? Обычно говорят о конкретных рынках,то есть европейский рынок газа, европейский рынок машиностроительного оборудования и др. В  каждой отрасли рынок образуют определенные страны, активные покупатели и продавцы данного вида продукции. В приведенном примере как раз и УТОЧНЯЕТСЯ список этих стран.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые нужны,т.к. в вашем примере несогласованные определения образуют ряд однородных членов предложения с предшествующими обособленным согласованным определением - Европейский

См. Академический справочник.

Comment: Не догадалась, что "с участием фирм ФРГ, Великобритании, Франции, Италии, Швеции"  - это несогласованное определение. Думала, обстоятельственный оборот. (Составляет как? С участием фирм ФРГ, Великобритании, Франции и т. д.) А про обстоятельства - я не знаю, всегда ли нужно обособление.

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу здесь "несогласованных определений с предшествующим согласованным..." 
"Рынок с участием фирм" - ну какое ж это несогласованное определение? 
Так что тут обособления тут авторские. От смысла сильно зависит. 
Если "с участим..." это раскрытие смысла "европейский рынок" - то да.

А если это, скажем, "EC плюс отдельные фирмы", то обособлять просто нельзя. Надо бы контекст.

Comment: Так ведь Великобритания, Франция, Швеция - это и есть Европа. Нет, здесь скорее раскрытие смысла "европейский рынок".

Comment: Подождите, что "нет" - и что "раскрытие смысла". Расшифруйте "европейский рынок" - это то, по вашему - фирмы отдельных стран?

Comment: Как могут к ЕС плюсоваться отдельные фирмы, которые в него уже входят? ЕС - это рынок всех фирм всех европейских стран. Как выясняется, предложение нужно было сформулировать как-то по-другому, например: Европейский рынок, в который входят фирмы ФРГ, Великобритании, Франции, Италии, Швеции, в годовом объеме производства различных видов арматуры составляет...

Comment: В ЕС входят государства, а не фирмы. Да и нет у меня уверенности, что здесь имеется в виду ЕС.

Comment: Да, вы правы... Я просто почему-то подумала, что ЕС - это ЕР - европейский рынок. Глупая ошибка. ЕС там действительно упоминается. Следующее предложение: Мировой рынок, включая ЕС, Японию, США вместе, — 11,88 млрд евро. Но меняется ли от этого смысл? Ведь страны, которые там перечислены, входят в ЕС.

Comment: Так вот я говорю, что фраза, если вдуматься, несколько странная, без контекста не поймешь, что там автор говорит -  и о каком рынке. Я понимаю "европейский рынок" как общий объем продаж (или производства) в определенном регионе. Как вот скажем, "фирма такая-то вышла на китайский рынок". Но в такой трактовке "уточнение" про принадлежность каких-то там фирм становится не просто излишним, но даже неправильным.

Comment: "Но меняется ли от этого смысл?" - я бы ответил на этот вопрос, если бы кто-то объяснил, что такое "рынок с участием". Я с этого начал. И жля чего здесь вообще упоминание всех этих разных прочих шведов. Если просто перечисление всех стран, где эта промышленность развита, то смысл не особо меняется. А вот если важно показать, что, к примеру, **только** эти страны  учитываются при подсчете... Или еще что-то... Просто не знаю, что автору могло в голову прийти при таком построении фразы. А потому и судить не берусь, что там у него меняется в плане смысла. А через это - и сомнения в пунктуации.